# Move the tool shelf panel to the other side?

Tags: interface

I somehow managed to flip the <kbd>T</kbd> *Tool Shelf* panel from the left side of the 3D viewport to the right side so it sits next to the <kbd>N</kbd> *Properties* panel.

How did I manage to do this and how do I move it back?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Move the mouse over the Tool Shelf and press <kbd>F5</kbd>. This can also be done with the Properties sidebar and headers.

Comment: Cool, that works most most everything!

Comment: I did this once and thought it was a bug :P +1!

Comment: I wanted to ask the same question but fortunally the answer is already here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi there, is there any way to accomplish this through other means? Hovering and pressing F5 on my Mac isn't working (it may have to do with the fact that I need to press Fn and then F5, because Mac makes F5 turn down the keyboard brightness). Thank you!

Comment: Found the answer here (hover and search for Flip Region): https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/154767/15400