# Moving the Properties Shelf to the right of the UI

Tags: interface

When I bring up the Properties Shelf (hotkey N) in 2.8, it appears aligned to the left side of my 3d viewport. Youtube tutorial videos I am watching show the Properties Shelf on the right side of the 3d viewport.  I have searched the Blender documentation, Google, Blenderartists, and I cannot find anywhere that shows how to realign this shelf to the right side!

How do I move the Properties shelf to the right side of thew viewport?

Comment: That is very strange. Does this happen with the startup file or just when loading old projects? Have you modified the preferences or installed a custom theme?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under blender 2.79 and previous there used to be a hot key for this that has been removed from 2.8 series.

The operator is called *Flip Region* and it switches the side a region (like the tool shelf or the properties sidebar) is docked to.

In 2.79 you could toggle it by hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> while hovering the relevant area, in 2.8# you have to call it from the menu.

The nuance is your mouse cursor must be hovering the region you want to affect when invoked, so move your mouse over to the properties region, press <kbd>Space bar</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd> (depending on your key config) type `Flip Region` and execute while the cursor is hovering the relevant sidebar.

[image]

---

For **2.9** Series.
You need to have **Developer Extras** on. Then you can follow the 2.8 series directions.

1. Top left of Blender's window, click **Edit** for a dropdown menu.
2. Then drop down to click **Preferences**. You'll get a **Popup Window**.
3. From the **Popup Window**, be sure to click **Interface** to open up Interface preferences.
4. Expand the **Display** panel.
5. Then turn on **Developer Extras** under the expanded **Display** panel.

[image: Getting to the Developer Extras]

*You can now follow the 2.8 series instructions. Go back up to the top of this answer for further instructions.*

No major UI changes have happened in the search menu in **2.90**
[image: Search menu]

Comment: Thank you Duarte.  Just an FYI, they also removed Spacebar as the search command hotkey in 2.8 - it is now F3!