# Reposition toolbox to right side in blender 2.9?

Tags: interface

Is there any way to re-position the toolbar on the left of the screen to the right?

(Sorry I don't know the official name, it looks like attached image)

It seems it's possible in 2.83 according to this [Moving the Properties Shelf to the right of the UI](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154752/moving-the-properties-shelf-to-the-right-of-the-ui/154767#154767),
but in 2.9 I can't find the "flip region" command.

Any ideas?

[image: ToolBar]

Comment: Still works in B2.9x beta. Place the cursor over the toolbar, press `F3` and type `flip region`... https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD469.png (flipped to the right already)

Comment: Thanks for replying ,for some reason this option is missing in my copy of blender 2.9 beta :https://imgur.com/a/V4IBwbS.